# Filtering columns only "if" certain condition is satisfied

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having table as below

[image]

And I want output as below

[image]

I tried doing something as below

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN2 = 'PQR' AND COLUMN3 IS NOT NULL
```

But it also removes `3rd and 4th row` from 1st table. Whereas in output of the query I need to remove only rows which are having `Column2 as PQR and Column3 as NOT NULL`

I also tried to use `case` statements but I'm not able to get actual idea of how to implement it.

EDIT 1:-

Also I thought of trying one more thing now.

`SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN2 IN ('PQR', 'XYZ', 'RST') AND COLUMN3 IS NOT NULL`

But the problem is in actual table `COLUMN2` is having more than 150 distinct values which I can't go on mentioning in `IN` clause.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `COLUMN2 = 'PQR' AND COLUMN3 IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @JNevill Apologies for inconvenience. I have edited the question.

Comment: Your explanation, queries and examples do not match, confuses. For this example you can simple write `where column3 is null`. But I suspect that you want something like this: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=20b1589d156e16e7aa258f2806266326).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. not(COLUMN2 = 'PQR' AND COLUMN3 IS NOT NULL)

Example:

```
SQL> ;
  1  with -- test data:
  2   t(column1,column2,column3) as (
  3     select 'ABC','PQR',cast(null as int) from dual union all
  4     select 'DEF','PQR',123 from dual union all
  5     select 'GHI','XYZ',cast(null as int) from dual union all
  6     select 'JKL','RST',cast(null as int) from dual
  7  ) -- test query:
  8  select *
  9  from t
 10* where not(COLUMN2 = 'PQR' AND COLUMN3 IS NOT NULL)
SQL> /

COL COL    COLUMN3
--- --- ----------
ABC PQR NULL
GHI XYZ NULL
JKL RST NULL
```

or  lnnvl(COLUMN2 = 'PQR') or COLUMN3 IS NULL

Example:

```
with -- test data:
 t(column1,column2,column3) as (
   select 'ABC','PQR',cast(null as int) from dual union all
   select 'DEF','PQR',123 from dual union all
   select 'GHI','XYZ',cast(null as int) from dual union all
   select 'JKL','RST',cast(null as int) from dual 
) -- test query:
select * 
from t
where lnnvl(COLUMN2 = 'PQR') or COLUMN3 IS NULL;

COL COL    COLUMN3
--- --- ----------
ABC PQR NULL
GHI XYZ NULL
JKL RST NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is (if I understood correctly)

```
NOT (COLUMN2 = 'PQR' AND COLUMN3 IS NOT NULL)
```

which is equivalent to

```
COLUMN2!='PQR' OR COLUMN3 IS NULL
```

Comment: But this will not show row having ``` PQR and NULL``` which is the first row of my example.

Comment: Did you try it? And you accepted the answer that says the same.

Comment: @gsalem "which is equivalent to" - to be honest that's not fully true: don't forget about NULLs - what if COLUMN2 is null but COLUMN3 is not null: first query will return it, but not your second query